# WebAPI2 Optional Parameters not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am attempting to have optional parameters for my WebAPI2 service function.
Here is the definition with the route:

```
[HttpGet, Route("mp/CEG/{ST?}/{PR?}/{DES?}"), ResponseType(typeof(CEG))]
public object CEG(string ST = null, string PR = null, string DES = null)
```

However, when I document it as below and attempt to run the test in the Swagger UI (built using Swashbuckle), 
all parameters state that they are required and I cannot submit a test with no paramters.

XMLDoc:

```
/// <summary>
///     Gets list of Apps for passed ST, PR and/or DES 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ST">ST</param>
/// <param name="PR">PR</param>
/// <param name="DES">DES</param>
/// <returns>List of CE Approvals</returns>
```

Any Ideas?

The function works with no parameters when running the functional test within Visual Studio.
It's just the SwaggerUI/Swashbuckle that is causing the issue. I am using that to give my consumers the chance to do tests.

**update to Routes**

```
[HttpGet, Route("mp/CEG/{ST}"),
          Route("mp/CEG/{PR}"),
          Route("mp/CEG/{DES}"),
          Route("mp/CEG/{ST}/{PR}"),
          Route("mp/CEG/{ST}/{DES}"),
          Route("mp/CEG/{PR}/{DES}"),
          ResponseType(typeof(CEG))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is not compliant with Swagger 2.0. As the [specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object) says about parameters (in my words):

> If the parameter is in "path", the parameter is always required.

Why don't you change the parameters to query parameters like so:

```
[HttpGet, Route("mp/CEG"), ResponseType(typeof(CEG))]
public object CEG(string ST = null, string PR = null, string DES = null)
```

Comment: WebAPI2 allows optional parameters in routes.Not sure what "path" you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, Web API does allow it, but Swagger does not. Hence my reference to the Swagger specification.

Comment: Well, that is crap. Isn't that essentially what Swagger is used for? How will that affect my documentation and the "test" option in the UI?

Comment: So, you mean I'd have to set all the different routes as I showed above?

Comment: If I do that, how does it determine which parameter is being sent?

Comment: I think you should read up on RESTful APIs. That's the kind of APIs Swagger is meant for. What RESTful is and what's not is a slippery topic but in my opinion you are putting query parameters in a path while the path should identify a resource. 

Btw, why can't you use my proposed solution? It creates a testable Swagger UI, it opens the way to create new methods on the same route (e.g `POST mp/CEG` to create a new CE approval).

Comment: I didn't think it would make the parameters avail in the UI. I just ran it and it does, so accepted.